# Need Help to Optimize SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i'm having a sql master table `CHANNEL_PT` 
which i want to fill based on two other master tables `CHANNEL` and `PT`.

the `CHANNEL_PT` cosist of three colums `CHANNEL_PT_CD`, `CHANNEL_CD` and `PT_CD`.

the scenario to insert records into `CHANNEL_PT` is such that,
if i am having two entries in the `CHANNEL` table,

[image]

and two entries in `PT` table as below,

[image]

then the `CHANNEL_PT` table would be as below

[image]

i knew that this can be done with `CURSOR` but i'm not using it due to performance concern.

**i have written the query as below to get the expected result but want to know any other more efficient way or optimized query.**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @CH INT;
DECLARE @CH_CNT INT;
DECLARE @CH_MAX INT; 
SELECT @CH_MAX = MAX(CHANNEL_CD) FROM CHANNEL;
SELECT @CH = ISNULL(MIN(CHANNEL_CD),0),@CH_CNT=COUNT(CHANNEL_CD) FROM CHANNEL WHERE CHANNEL_CD > -1

WHILE @CH <= @CH_MAX

BEGIN
    DECLARE @PT INT;
    DECLARE @PT_CNT INT;
    DECLARE @PT_MAX INT; 
    SELECT @PT_MAX = MAX(PT_CD) FROM PT;
    SELECT @PT = ISNULL(MIN(PT_CD),0),@PT_CNT=COUNT(PT_CD) FROM PT WHERE PT_CD > -1
    WHILE @PT <=@PT_MAX
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @CPT INT;
            SELECT @CPT = ISNULL(MAX(CHANNEL_PT_CD),0) FROM CHANNEL_PT
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT CHANNEL_CD,PT_CD FROM CHANNEL_PT WHERE CHANNEL_CD=@CH and PT_CD=@PT)
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO CHANNEL_PT VALUES(@CPT+1,@CH,@PT)
                END
            SELECT @PT = MIN(PT_CD) FROM PT WHERE PT_CD > @PT
        END 
    SELECT @CH=MIN(CHANNEL_CD) FROM CHANNEL WHERE CHANNEL_CD > @CH
END
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Cursors are in most cases slower than set-based operations. But you replace the cursor with a while loop which is even slower.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are describing a cross join.  Is column CHANNEL_PT_CD defined as an IDENTITY column?  That removes the need for you to assign that value since the server will do it for you.

Then you can do a simple INSERT/SELECT

```
INSERT INTO CHANNEL_PT
SELECT b.CHANNEL_CD, c.PT
  FROM CHANNEL b 
 cross join PT c
```

Comment: CHANNEL_PT_CD is not an IDENTITY column

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
DECLARE @CPT INT=0;
SELECT @CPT = ISNULL(MAX(CHANNEL_PT_CD),0) FROM CHANNEL_PT

INSERT INTO CHANNEL_PT
SELECT DISTINCT @CPT+ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY b.CHANNEL_CD),
     b.CHANNEL_CD, 
     c.PT
FROM CHANNEL b, PT c
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CHANNEL_PT a 
       WHERE a.CHANNEL_CD=b.CHANNEL_CD AND a.PT_CD=c.PT)=0
```